# What is the default Enster IP Camera's username and password?

Tags: authentication, default-settings, ip-camera, factory-defaults

I have an [Enster PTZ Cameras](https://www.enster.com/). My model number specifically is [NST-IPC7175-W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09T6DDW5H). When I boot this camera up, I can see exposed on the network as 192.168.1.88, however the printed instructions don't tell me a username and password. Instead, they ask me to download [CamHipro from the Android Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hichip.campro&gl=US) to set this camera up. This is a bit fishy for me the developer is [franck](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=franck&gl=US), but it seems this isn't a typo or anything: the [website also references CamHi](https://www.enster.com/enster-support/Camhi-Download) and there is a non-pro version also in the [Play Store of of CamHi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hichip&gl=US).

Is there another way to set this camera up that doesn't require installing questionable software on my cell phone.

Comment: What makes you think the software running on the camera itself is *not* questionable?

Comment: @StarCat I control my network with egress and ingress. I do not control my cell phone network. I also don't care what the camera does so long as I know who it's talking to, not talking to, and does what I want it to do.

Comment: @StarCat Also if you're suggesting a PTZ camera with nightvision and h.265 hw encoding with optical zoom that's open source PLEASE TELL ME. Shopping for this stuff is a gigantic time suck. This was the best I could do. And I'm glad I got away with it so cheap, and with reasonable build quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the default user name of `admin` and the default password of `admin`. That's what this camera is set to use.